# Proofs that says finiteness is required because you need to take the min/max

Tags: real-analysis

There are some proofs in topology and real analysis that requires a set to be finite because you need to take the max or min for the proof. An example would be that finite intersection of open sets are open. You take a point and an epsilon ball for all the open sets and then you take the minimum epsilon so you can find a neighbor that works for all the open sets. In almost all textbooks, they state that this proof works because you can take the minimum of a finite set which is true. But there are infinite sets where you can also take the minimum. All closed sets of the form [a,b] or [a, infinity) has a minimum (a). Of course open intervals do not contain their minimums, but why is it the case that we are assuming the cases where the minimum does not exist? Basically, why are we assuming in some proofs that the infinity we are talking about are the sets that does not contain a minimum versus the sets that do contains their minimum?

Comment: Also want to add. I know why infinite intersections of open sets are not open and I know the counterexamples.

Comment: Some infinite sets have a minimum, e.g. the positive integers, and some don't, e.g. the negative integers.  So, finiteness makes life simpler.  Also, as you mention, in your comment some properties are not preserved in the infinite case.  Read it as "because the set is finite, we can certainly find the minimum and maximum" not as "if it were not finite then we certainly could not".